# How can a string that does not belongs to the input language can set a turing machine in a infinite loop?

Tags: infinite-loop, theory, computation-theory, turing-machines, input-language

How is it possible to set a turing machine in infinite loop by putting a string that doesn't belong to input language even if it has a reject state?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming problem. It is a question about the theory of computation. If you have a programming problem, please show the code that is not working.

Comment: @RaymondChen - I agree

Comment: @RaymondChen That's OK. But where do I post this question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the TM that does the following:

1. Read a tape cell. If 0, halt accept. If 1, write 1, move right, and enter state 2.
2. Read a tape cell. If 0, halt reject If 1, write 1, move left, and enter state 1.

This machine accepts strings 0* + 10*. It does not accept anything in 11* but it will loop forever on such a string.

Comment: Thanks you very much.